# I can't push or commit files to github with visual studio code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, github-for-windows

I tried to solve this issue using the duplicates of this question, but so far nothing has worked.

Git Status yields these results

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 15 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:
        deleted:    rockpaperscissors
```

When I try to commit the changes in the main branch it says the following

```
$ git commit
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Users/Dume/rps/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

I deleted the index.lock file within VSC but it seems to keep coming back

I've also tried deleting the repository in Github completely and replacing it with a new one, but nothing has changed.

I'm at a loss of what to do next

Comment: The *first* thing you generally want to do after you've resolved your merge conflcts is `git add xyz` the updated files.  This could easily resolve the entire problem: https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/git-tutorial/merge-conflicts-in-git

Comment: I tried git add . But that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The index is the part of Git that keeps track of which files are to be staged for the next commit.  When Git wants to write a new copy of the index because some program is updating it, it creates the file `index.lock`, failing if it already exists, writes the new content to it, and then atomically replaces the old index with the new file.

You're seeing this `index.lock` file persisting for one of a couple reasons:

- Something on your system is trying to update the index and never completing.  This could be some tool that's invoking Git with a long-running process, or a program, maybe your editor, using libgit2 to create an index on disk and then never committing it.
- Some Git utility on your system is actually crashing.  This is probably not very likely.
- Something on your system is preventing the atomic replacement from working, which can leave the `index.lock` file behind.  Windows has a bunch of weird rules about when you can and can't do an atomic replacement which don't exist on Unix.

My guess here is that you have some other process on the system interfering with your repository.  If your repository is in a cloud-synced storage bucket (e.g., OneDrive or Dropbox), that could be the cause; those are known to break things and corrupt repositories.  It could be some sort of antivirus or firewall other than the default (Windows Defender and Windows Firewall), or other tools that monitor stuff on the system.

It's also possible that something about your editor, your editor Git integration, or an editor plugin is causing the problem.  There are really just a huge number of possibilities and it's hard to say.

I would definitely move all repositories out of cloud-synced storage, use only Windows Defender and Windows Firewall, and try to access Git only from the command line, turning off any editor integrations, and see if you still see the problem.  If you still do, look for any error messages that might give you a clue, and try to correlate the behavior with whatever else is going on during that point.

Comment: I'll try but before I do, am I allowed to add screenshots here? There's a git commit message in my source control section that refuses to go away no matter what I do. It says "Merge branch 'main' of https://github.com/Bl1xvan/rockpaperscissors".  There is also a deleted cached folder named "rockpaperscissors". I tried unstaging it but it won't work. I get a message saying index.lock exists. Does this change anything?

Comment: You probably have a submodule of some sort involved here, but that is going to be a separate issue which you should ask in a separate question once you've got this solved.

Comment: So what solved this for me was deleting the .git folder completely. The I added, commited and pushed everything into the master branch on github. So now my site is deployed.